# Mschart get value of a series at the cursor position

Tags: c#, mschart

I have an [mschart](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) with values and a cursor line moving based on a timer. Is it possible to get the value of a specific series at the cursor position?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string ceva = detailChart.Series[1].Points[detailChart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Position].GetValueByName("Y").ToString(
```

Comment: It does not work, CursorX.Position returns a double coordinate not an int index as Points[...] need!

Answer (score 4):

You can get current DataPoint value with MouseMove event handler.

```
private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  var source = sender as Chart;
  HitTestResult result = source.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

  if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint && result.PointIndex != -1)
  {     
    var xValaue = source.Series[0].Points[result.PointIndex].XValue;
    var yValaue = source.Series[0].Points[result.PointIndex].YValues[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: You could always replace Series[0] with Series[result.Series.Name] to make it work on multiple series (or just work with the result.Series object directly).